# Data is showing in Realtime but not updating in Overview Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a site where I set up Google analytics using the Gscript code which I pasted it on header file of my website. Everything was working fine but from yesterday, Data is reflecting in Realtime but not reflecting in Overview. I am not highly experienced in Analytics, So please help me out.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait 24h before seeing data in the reports.